# SD card Mounting Copying and file recovery

Tags: mount, data-recovery, sd-card, dd

My micro sd card stopped being recognized by my win2008 computer after a copy paste failure (maybe the card was full? or the antivirus stalled it and now the MBR is corrupted?).  Now I want to see if I can mount my sd card on my Ubuntu machine, and then make a copy of the image file, so that I can perform a file recovery on it.  What do you think?  How can I do it, and will it work?

Answer (score 0):

First try to simply insert the microSD card and see if ubuntu recognizes it.
If yes, then copy all the files from it, reformat the SD card, and copy back the files...

Comment: The card could not be read in the Samsung S3 it came out of. I put it in my Win computer and copied some photos from it. Then I saw more photos in another folder so I tried to copy all the files from the card. It stalled in the copy paste function. I tried pulling it out and putting it back in. Maybe that was the fatal move. But it stopped being recognizable. So I tried my asus eeepc running Ubuntu, and it doesn't recognize that there is an sd card installed.  I tried another card so I knew which drive I was looking for (sdc) but nothing.  I even tried a new USB sd card adapter (sdd) nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a file recovery tool to help you fix your micro card.
CardRecoveryPro can recover your files, you can download here:http://tinyurl.com/bhcwmj2
then follow these steps:

1. Download and install CardRecoveryPro.
2. Choose the drive to start scanning.
3. After scanning, list of file types will be displayed in the left
   pane.
4. Click each file type to view files in it. You will see thumbnails
   when you click on the file type.
5. You can either recover all or part files by clicking the Recovery
   button.